# 2x3 custom button grid layout doesn't fit TableRow

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am developing some sort of player with 2x3 grid of custom buttons... Buttons are made in customplayerbutton.xml and then they are used as "includes" in main.xml There is a problem with layout - my custom buttons do not fit the TableRow:

[bad layout http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/6492/badlayout.png](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/6492/badlayout.png)

What am I doing wrong?

customplayerbutton.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Track67890"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="99:99:999 / 99:99:999"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" >

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include01"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" >

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include02"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include04"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" >

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include03"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include05"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved this by replacing TableLayout to LinearLayout. Here is the xml worked to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" >

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include01"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include00"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" >

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include02"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include04"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" >

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include03"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/include05"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    layout="@layout/customplayerbutton" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the XML layouts you posted, i didn't got the output as you shown here, but i got differently. Then i removed 2 statements from `main.xml` file, now the output is good.

Try this.

In 1st `<TableRow>` 1st `<include>` remove the line `android:layout_gravity="left"`
and 2nd `<include>` remove the line `android:layout_gravity="right"`

Comment: Removing layout_gravity tags will not help. They affect in case if screen size is larger than needed, and in that case first two buttons are gravitated to the left and right edges of the layout. To get the output on the screen-shot you should have a low-inch (3.2' is good) display. It behaves, as includes have android:layout_width not "fill_parent", but "wrap_content".